# Java, escaping (using) quotes in a regex

Tags: java, regex, escaping

I'm trying to use the following regex in Java, that's supposed to match any `lang="2-char-lang-name"`:

```
String lang = "lang=\"" + L.detectLang(inputText) +"\"";
shovel.replaceFirst("lang=\"[..]\"", lang);
```

I know that a single slash would be interpreted by regex as a slash and not an escape character (so my code doesn't work), but if I escape the slash, the `"` won't be escaped any more and I'd get a syntax error.

In other words, how can I include a `"` in the regex? `"lang=\\"[..]\\""` won't work. I've also tried three slashes and that didn't have any matches either.

I am also aware of the general rule that you don't use regex to parse XML/HTML. (and `shovel` is an XML) However, all I'm doing is, looking for a `lang` attribute that is within the first 30 characters of the XML, and I want to replace it. Is it really a bad idea to use regex in this case? I don't think using DOM would be any better/more efficient.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escaping special characters in Java Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664434/escaping-special-characters-in-java-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Three slashes would be correct (`\\` + `\"` becomes `\` + `"` = `\"`). (**Update**: Actually, it turns out that isn't even necessary. A single slash also works, it seems.) The problem is your use of `[..]`; the `[]` symbols mean "any of the characters in here" (so `[..]` just means "any character").

Drop the `[]` and you should be getting what you want:

```
String ab = "foo=\"bar\" lang=\"AB\"";
String regex = "lang=\\\"..\\\"";
String cd = ab.replaceFirst(regex, "lang=\"CD\"");
System.out.println(cd);
```

Output:

```
foo="bar" lang="CD"
```

Comment: ah yes, I hadn't really parsed what he was doing there with the `[..]`. I think that inside a `[]`, the `.` is interpreted literally, so `[..]` means "any single character which is either a `.` or a `.`".

Comment: Dang... You're right, 'guess my regex has gotten way too rusty. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried it with a single backslash? The output of

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String inputString = "<xml lang=\"the Queen's English\">";
  System.out.println(inputString.replaceFirst("lang=\"[^\"]*\"", "lang=\"American\"" ));
}
```

is

```
<xml lang="American">
```

which, if I'm reading you correctly, is what you want.

EDIT to add: the reason a single backslash works is that it's not actually part of the string, it's just part of the syntax for expressing the string.  The length of the string `"\""` is 1, not 2, and the method `replaceFirst` just sees a string containing a `"` (with no backslash).  This is why e.g. `\s` (the whitespace character class in a regex) has to be written `\\s` in a Java string literal.

On the wisdom of using regex: this should be fine, if you're sure about the format of the files you're processing. If the files might include a commented-out header complete with `lang` spec above the real header, you could be in trouble!

Comment: No, it's well formed xml with standards and whatnot. Thanks for pointing out that a single slash would work. I thought it wouldn't since it's also a regex special character.

Comment: The regex does not see the single slash. The single slash is part of how strings are written in java, so "\"" is a string of length 1. So is "\\", which is a string containing a slash, which as you say is a regex metacharacter. "\\\\" is a string of length 2. If you pass this as a regex, the first slash escapes the second in this case.