# Escaping special characters in Java Regular Expressions

Tags: java, regex, escaping

Is there any method in Java or any open source library for escaping (not quoting) a special character (meta-character), in order to use it as a regular expression?

This would be very handy in dynamically building a regular expression, without having to manually escape each individual character.

For example, consider a simple regex like `\d+\.\d+` that matches numbers with a decimal point like `1.2`, as well as the following code:

```
String digit = "d";
String point = ".";
String regex1 = "\\d+\\.\\d+";
String regex2 = Pattern.quote(digit + "+" + point + digit + "+");

Pattern numbers1 = Pattern.compile(regex1);
Pattern numbers2 = Pattern.compile(regex2);

System.out.println("Regex 1: " + regex1);

if (numbers1.matcher("1.2").matches()) {
    System.out.println("\tMatch");
} else {
    System.out.println("\tNo match");
}

System.out.println("Regex 2: " + regex2);

if (numbers2.matcher("1.2").matches()) {
    System.out.println("\tMatch");
} else {
    System.out.println("\tNo match");
}
```

Not surprisingly, the output produced by the above code is:

```
Regex 1: \d+\.\d+
    Match
Regex 2: \Qd+.d+\E
    No match
```

That is, `regex1` matches `1.2` but `regex2` (which is "dynamically" built) does not (instead, it matches the literal string `d+.d+`).

So, is there a method that would automatically escape each regex meta-character?

If there were, let's say, a static `escape()` method in `java.util.regex.Pattern`, the output of

```
Pattern.escape('.')
```

would be the string `"\."`, but

```
Pattern.escape(',')
```

should just produce `","`, since it is not a meta-character. Similarly,

```
Pattern.escape('d')
```

could produce `"\d"`, since `'d'` is used to denote digits (although escaping may not make sense in this case, as `'d'` could mean literal `'d'`, which wouldn't be misunderstood by the regex interpeter to be something else, as would be the case with `'.'`).

Comment: How would such a method determine the difference beween a `d` meant as meta character and a `d` in text to match? (`quote("d+ Dollars?")` would become `"\\d+ \\Dollar\\s?"` in a trivial quoting method.)

Comment: Correct, which is exactly why I am asking for a method that would escape individual characters! :-)

Comment: To escape only individual characters you might play around with matching a word boundary, something like: `s/\b([dswDSW])\b/\\$1/g;`

Comment: For sure, there are numerous ways of doing this "manually" (even by having a table of characters and comparing each time), but I am essentially asking whether someone has done this already.

Comment: Can you take a step back and explain _why_ you want this method?  Why don't you just use "\\d"?  If you know you want a digit, why not just have a constant string which does that.  Why have a whole method that just prepends "\\"?

Comment: Because, as the question mentions, I want to dynamically build the regular expression, base on user input.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Is there any method in Java or any open source library for escaping (not quoting) a special character (meta-character), in order to use it as a regular expression?

If you are looking for a way to create constants that you can use in your regex patterns, then just prepending them with `"\\"` should work but there is no nice `Pattern.escape('.')` function to help with this.

So if you are trying to match `"\\d"` (the string `\d` instead of a decimal character) then you would do:

```
// this will match on \d as opposed to a decimal character
String matchBackslashD = "\\\\d";
// as opposed to
String matchDecimalDigit = "\\d";
```

The 4 slashes in the Java string turn into 2 slashes in the regex pattern.  2 backslashes in a regex pattern matches the backslash itself.  Prepending any special character with backslash turns it into a normal character instead of a special one.

```
matchPeriod = "\\.";
matchPlus = "\\+";
matchParens = "\\(\\)";
...
```

In your post you use the [`Pattern.quote(string)` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29).  This method wraps your pattern between `"\\Q"` and `"\\E"` so you can match a string even if it happens to have a special regex character in it (`+`, `.`, `\\d`, etc.)

Comment: I know about quote() and if you look at the sample output above it includes \Q and \E. Indeed, I was just looking for a method to produce the escaped version of a character for a Java regex. So, for instance, the escaped comma would remain a comma, but the escaped period should become \. and so on.

Answer (score 40):

I wrote this pattern:

```
Pattern SPECIAL_REGEX_CHARS = Pattern.compile("[{}()\\[\\].+*?^$\\\\|]");
```

And use it in this method:

```
String escapeSpecialRegexChars(String str) {

    return SPECIAL_REGEX_CHARS.matcher(str).replaceAll("\\\\$0");
}
```

Then you can use it like this, for example:

```
Pattern toSafePattern(String text)
{
    return Pattern.compile(".*" + escapeSpecialRegexChars(text) + ".*");
}
```

We needed to do that because, after escaping, we add some regex expressions. If not, you can simply use `\Q` and `\E`:

```
Pattern toSafePattern(String text)
{
    return Pattern.compile(".*\\Q" + text + "\\E.*")
}
```

Comment: This one didn't work for me (at least in Scala), but this one did: `"[\\{\\}\\(\\)\\[\\]\\.\\+\\*\\?\\^\\$\\\\\\|]"`

Comment: There's a complete list of special chars here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27454382/1490986

Comment: The escapeSpecialRegexChars for me needed to be escaped again:
```
    public static String escapeSpecialRegexChars(String str) {
        return SPECIAL_REGEX_CHARS.matcher(str).replaceAll("\\\\\\\\$0");
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

The only way the regex matcher knows you are looking for a digit and not the letter `d` is to escape the letter (`\d`).  To type the regex escape character in java, you need to escape it (so `\` becomes `\\`).  So, there's no way around typing double backslashes for special regex chars.

Comment: Exactly, so I want a method that would escape a character into a regex  (i.e., not a literal) string.

Comment: You could write your own `escape()` method that prepends `"\\"` to its parameter

Comment: To be clear about terminology, adding a backslash to a non-special character is not called escaping. To write `\d` does not in any way "escape the letter" `d`. It instead creates a completely distinct concept, a character class that represents digits. An example of escaping would be your second case, writing `\\` to represent the slash character.

Answer (score 8):

The `Pattern.quote(String s)` sort of does what you want. However it leaves a little left to be desired; it doesn't actually escape the individual characters, just wraps the string with `\Q...\E`.

There is not a method that does exactly what you are looking for, but the good news is that it is actually fairly simple to escape all of the special characters in a Java regular expression:

```
regex.replaceAll("[\\W]", "\\\\$0")
```

Why does this work? Well, the documentation for [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bs) specifically says that its permissible to escape non-alphabetic characters that don't necessarily have to be escaped:

> It is an error to use a backslash prior to any alphabetic character that does not denote an escaped construct; these are reserved for future extensions to the regular-expression language. **A backslash may be used prior to a non-alphabetic character regardless of whether that character is part of an unescaped construct.**

For example, `;` is not a special character in a regular expression. However, if you escape it, `Pattern` will still interpret `\;` as `;`. Here are a few more examples:

- `>` becomes `\>` which is equivalent to `>`
- `[` becomes `\[` which is the escaped form of `[`
- `8` is still `8`.
- `\)` becomes `\\\)` which is the escaped forms of `\` and `(` concatenated.

**Note:** The key is is the definition of "non-alphabetic", which in the documentation really means "non-*word*" characters, or characters outside the character set `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`.

Comment: Do you mean periods?

Comment: exactly, I am now using the solution from here (iterating through the string): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134558/list-of-all-special-characters-that-need-to-be-escaped-in-a-regex

Answer (score 5):

Use this Utility function `escapeQuotes()` in order to escape strings in between ***Groups*** and ***Sets*** of a [`RegularExpression`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/).

*List of Regex Literals to escape [**`<([{\^-=$!|]})?*+.>`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html)*

```java
public class RegexUtils {
    static String escapeChars = "\\.?![]{}()<>*+-=^$|";
    public static String escapeQuotes(String str) {
        if(str != null && str.length() > 0) {
            return str.replaceAll("[\\W]", "\\\\$0"); // \W designates non-word characters
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

*From the [**Pattern**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class the backslash character `('\')` serves to introduce escaped constructs. The string literal `"\(hello\)"` is illegal and leads to a compile-time error; in order to match the string (hello) the string literal `"\\(hello\\)"` must be used.*

***Example***: String to be matched `(hello)` and the regex with a group is `(\(hello\))`. Form here you only need to escape matched string as shown below. <sup>[`Test Regex online`](https://regex101.com/)</sup>

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String matched = "(hello)", regexExpGrup = "(" + escapeQuotes(matched) + ")";
    System.out.println("Regex : "+ regexExpGrup); // (\(hello\))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Gray, as you may need your pattern to have both litrals (\[, \]) and meta-characters ([, ]). so with some utility you should be able to escape all character first and then you can add meta-characters you want to add on same pattern.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
pattern.compile("\"");
String s= p.toString()+"yourcontent"+p.toString();
```

will give result as `yourcontent` as is