# How to get a string between two characters?

Tags: java, string

I have a string,

```
String s = "test string (67)";
```

I want to get the no 67 which is the string between ( and ).

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: There are several ways - you could iterate the chars in the string until you reach the `(` or find the index of the first `(` and `)` and do it with substring or, what most people would do, use a regular expression.

Answer (score 136):

There's probably a really neat RegExp, but I'm noob in that area, so instead...

```
String s = "test string (67)";

s = s.substring(s.indexOf("(") + 1);
s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(")"));

System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Without going through the oddities of regex parsing, I think this is the best way to extract the required string.

Comment: regex is by far more powerful and can take in more cases, but for simplicity, this works...

Comment: Seriously, why would this attract a down vote? Does it it not work? Does it not answer the ops question?

Comment: if I have multiple values then how can I use substring consider i have string like this `'this is an example of <how><i have it>'` and i need to find values between '<' and '>' this

Comment: @Vignesh Use a regular expression

Comment: can you give me an example I had tied it but could not get the desired output..How to specify the special characters in regex.@MadProgrammer

Comment: @Vignesh [Regular Expression to find a string included between two characters while EXCLUDING the delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclud)

Comment: hi @MadProgrammer i have tried to get the value from following code but could not get is `var regex = /<(.*?)\>/g;
var str = "<card>,<tech>";
var match = regex.exec(str);
match;` my code is as about only getting `card` i also want `tech` in output

Comment: @MadProgrammer - what about performance? when one has to repeat this for several millions of strings?

Comment: @MasterJoe2 I couldn't tell you, spinning up a regular expression engine will have some overhead, but then again, you might be able to do that ahead of time and re-use it

Comment: This is problematic unless you only ever have those characters where you want the string. ie.  with String s = "test string 67:"; where you want the the string between a SPACE and a COLON. There are other spaces, so this won't work. So this is not specifically looking for the string between those two characters.

Comment: @SupermanKelly Any solution is going to need to be tweaked for individual needs, for example, I often find that I start with a wide match and then narrow it down, often over a number of requests

Comment: @SupermanKelly So, I that very specific case, I'd consider finding the `;` and the find the index of the last "space", so a two step workflow - but if you can make a RegExp that works, I might consider that instead - but you'd need to focus on what you're trying to achieve and find the solution(s) which will work for your specific case

Answer (score 132):

A very useful solution to this issue which doesn't require from you to do the indexOf is using **Apache Commons** libraries.

```
 StringUtils.substringBetween(s, "(", ")");
```

This  method will allow you even handle even if there multiple occurrences of the closing string which wont be easy by looking for indexOf closing string.

You can download this library from here:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.4

Comment: There's also `substringsBetween(...)` if you expect multiple results, which is what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Link with more example-  https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substringsBetween(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not produce all possible combinations, when you have a string like: "a-b-c-d-e". I expect to have: b, c, d. Whereas the actual result is: b, d. In other words, it gives you combinations with mutually excluded separators only.

Answer (score 86):

Try it like this

```
String s="test string(67)";
String requiredString = s.substring(s.indexOf("(") + 1, s.indexOf(")"));
```

The method's signature for substring is:

```
s.substring(int start, int end);
```

Answer (score 31):

By using regular expression :

```
 String s = "test string (67)";
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(.*?\\)");
 Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
 if(m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group().subSequence(1, m.group().length()-1));
```

Comment: I think you should make this a non-greedy match by using ".*?" instead. Otherwise, if the string is soemthing like "test string (67) and (68), this will return "67) and (68".

Answer (score 20):

[Java supports Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/), but they're kind of cumbersome if you actually want to use them to extract matches. I think the easiest way to get at the string you want in your example is to just use the Regular Expression support in the `String` class's `replaceAll` method:

```
String x = "test string (67)".replaceAll(".*\\(|\\).*", "");
// x is now the String "67"
```

This simply deletes everything up-to-and-including the first `(`, and the same for the `)` and everything thereafter. This just leaves the stuff between the parenthesis.

However, the result of this is still a `String`. If you want an integer result instead then you need to do another conversion:

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(x);
// n is now the integer 67
```

Answer (score 12):

In a single line, I suggest:

```java
String input = "test string (67)";
input = input.subString(input.indexOf("(")+1, input.lastIndexOf(")"));
System.out.println(input);`
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use apache common library's StringUtils to do this.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
...
String s = "test string (67)";
s = StringUtils.substringBetween(s, "(", ")");
....
```

Answer (score 8):

Test String `test string (67)` from which you need to get the String which is nested in-between two Strings.

```java
String str = "test string (67) and (77)", open = "(", close = ")";
```

**Listed some possible ways**: Simple Generic Solution:

```java
String subStr = str.substring(str.indexOf( open ) + 1, str.indexOf( close ));
System.out.format("String[%s] Parsed IntValue[%d]\n", subStr, Integer.parseInt( subStr ));
```

---

> Apache Software Foundation [`commons.lang3`](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang).

[`StringUtils`](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.java) class `substringBetween()` function gets the String that is nested in between two Strings. Only the first match is returned.

```java
String substringBetween = StringUtils.substringBetween(subStr, open, close);
System.out.println("Commons Lang3 : "+ substringBetween);
```

*Replaces the given String, with the String which is nested in between two Strings. [`#395`](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/pull/395)*

---

> Pattern with Regular-Expressions: [**`(\()(.*?)(\)).*`**](https://regex101.com/r/ONalwP/2)

The [Dot](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) Matches (Almost) Any Character
 `.? = .{0,1}, .* = .{0,}, .+ = .{1,}`

```java
String patternMatch = patternMatch(generateRegex(open, close), str);
System.out.println("Regular expression Value : "+ patternMatch);
```

*Regular-Expression with the utility class [**`RegexUtils`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54087458/5081877) and some functions.*

      **`Pattern.DOTALL`**: *Matches any character, including a line terminator.*

      **`Pattern.MULTILINE`**: *Matches entire String from the start`^` till end`$` of the input sequence.*

```java
public static String generateRegex(String open, String close) {
    return "(" + RegexUtils.escapeQuotes(open) + ")(.*?)(" + RegexUtils.escapeQuotes(close) + ").*";
}

public static String patternMatch(String regex, CharSequence string) {
    final Pattern pattern  = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern .matcher(string);

    String returnGroupValue = null;
    if (matcher.find()) { // while() { Pattern.MULTILINE }
        System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
        System.out.format("Character Index [Start:End]«[%d:%d]\n",matcher.start(),matcher.end());
        for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            if( i == 2 ) returnGroupValue = matcher.group( 2 );
        }
    }
    return returnGroupValue;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
String s = "test string (67)";

int start = 0; // '(' position in string
int end = 0; // ')' position in string
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) { 
    if(s.charAt(i) == '(') // Looking for '(' position in string
       start = i;
    else if(s.charAt(i) == ')') // Looking for ')' position in  string
       end = i;
}
String number = s.substring(start+1, end); // you take value between start and end
```

Answer (score 7):

```
String result = s.substring(s.indexOf("(") + 1, s.indexOf(")"));
```

Comment: Please format your code by indenting 4 spaces. Also I would pad out your answer a little by explaining what your code does for those visiting who are unsure what `.substring` and .indexOf` does.

Answer (score 5):

```
public String getStringBetweenTwoChars(String input, String startChar, String endChar) {
    try {
        int start = input.indexOf(startChar);
        if (start != -1) {
            int end = input.indexOf(endChar, start + startChar.length());
            if (end != -1) {
                return input.substring(start + startChar.length(), end);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return input; // return null; || return "" ;
}
```

Usage :

```
String input = "test string (67)";
String startChar = "(";
String endChar   = ")";
String output = getStringBetweenTwoChars(input, startChar, endChar);
System.out.println(output);
// Output: "67"
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way of doing using split method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    String s = "test string (67)";
    String[] ss;
    ss= s.split("\\(");
    ss = ss[1].split("\\)");

    System.out.println(ss[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `Pattern and Matcher`

```
public class Chk {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "test string (67)";
        ArrayList<String> arL = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> inL = new ArrayList<String>();

        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\(\\w+\\)");
        Matcher mat = pat.matcher(s);

        while (mat.find()) {

            arL.add(mat.group());
            System.out.println(mat.group());

        }

        for (String sx : arL) {

            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(sx);

            while (m.find()) {

                inL.add(m.group());
                System.out.println(m.group());
            }
        }

        System.out.println(inL);

    }

}
```

Comment: Speaking variable names could make method more friendly.

Answer (score 3):

The "generic" way of doing this is to parse the string from the start, throwing away all the characters before the first bracket, recording the characters after the first bracket, and throwing away the characters after the second bracket.

I'm sure there's a regex library or something to do it though.

Comment: Java supports regular expressions. No need for a regexp4j library ;)

Answer (score 3):

The least generic way I found to do this with Regex and Pattern / Matcher classes:

```
String text = "test string (67)";

String START = "\\(";  // A literal "(" character in regex
String END   = "\\)";  // A literal ")" character in regex

// Captures the word(s) between the above two character(s)
String pattern = START + "(\w+)" + END;

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group()
        .replace(START, "").replace(END, ""));
}
```

This may help for more complex regex problems where you want to get the text between two set of characters.

Answer (score 3):

The other possible solution is to use **[`lastIndexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf-java.lang.String-int-)** where it will look for character or String from backward.

In my scenario, I had following `String` and I had to extract `<<UserName>>`

```
1QAJK-WKJSH_MyApplication_Extract_<<UserName>>.arc
```

So, `indexOf` and `StringUtils.substringBetween` was not helpful as they start looking for character from beginning.

So, I used `lastIndexOf`

```
String str = "1QAJK-WKJSH_MyApplication_Extract_<<UserName>>.arc";
String userName = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("_") + 1, str.lastIndexOf("."));
```

And, it gives me

```
<<UserName>>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = "test string (67)";

System.out.println(s.substring(s.indexOf("(")+1,s.indexOf(")")));
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
public static String innerSubString(String txt, char prefix, char suffix) {

    if(txt != null && txt.length() > 1) {

        int start = 0, end = 0;
        char token;
        for(int i = 0; i < txt.length(); i++) {
            token = txt.charAt(i);
            if(token == prefix)
                start = i;
            else if(token == suffix)
                end = i;
        }

        if(start + 1 < end)
            return txt.substring(start+1, end);

    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it will return original string if no match regex

```
var iAm67 = "test string (67)".replaceFirst("test string \\((.*)\\)", "$1");
```

add matches to the code

```
String str = "test string (67)";
String regx = "test string \\((.*)\\)";
if (str.matches(regx)) {
    var iAm67 = str.replaceFirst(regx, "$1");
}
```

---EDIT---

i use https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output to test regex.

turn out it's better to add ? after * for less match. something like this:

```
String str = "test string (67)(69)";
String regx1 = "test string \\((.*)\\).*";
String regx2 = "test string \\((.*?)\\).*";
String ans1 = str.replaceFirst(regx1, "$1");
String ans2 = str.replaceFirst(regx2, "$1");
System.out.println("ans1:"+ans1+"\nans2:"+ans2); 
// ans1:67)(69
// ans2:67
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple use `\D+` regex and job done. 
This select all chars except digits, no need to complicate

```
/\D+/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "(69)";
System.out.println(s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('(')+1,s.lastIndexOf(')')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Little extension to top (MadProgrammer) answer

```
 public static String getTextBetween(final String wholeString, final String str1, String str2){
    String s = wholeString.substring(wholeString.indexOf(str1) + str1.length());
    s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(str2));
    return s;
}
```