# Extract string between two strings in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I try to get string between <%= and %>, here is my implementation:

```
String str = "ZZZZL <%= dsn %> AFFF <%= AFG %>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<%=(.*?)%>");
String[] result = pattern.split(str);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

it return

```
[ZZZZL ,  AFFF ]
```

But my expectation is:

```
[ dsn , AFG ]
```

Where am i wrong and how to correct it ?

Comment: It's appears you're confusing *splitting* a string with pattern matching.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Your pattern is fine. But you shouldn't be `split()`ting it away, you should `find()` it. Following code gives the output you are looking for:

```
String str = "ZZZZL <%= dsn %> AFFF <%= AFG %>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<%=(.*?)%>", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: I added `Pattern.DOTALL` for those quite common cases when the expected match spans across multiple lines.

Answer (score 60):

I have answered this question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38238785/1773972

Basically use

```
StringUtils.substringBetween(str, "<%=", "%>");
```

This requirs using "Apache commons lang" library:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.4

This library has a lot of useful methods for working with string, you will really benefit from exploring this library in other areas of your java code !!!

Comment: I seriously dont understand why do we need to add a new dependency jar/library all together in the project  just to acheive a small trivial funcionality

Comment: Adding dependencies has become a joke  :)

Comment: @Stunner, you are right, it's overkill. But this answer is mostly for those who already have commons-lang3 in their classpath.

Answer (score 8):

Jlordo approach covers specific situation. If you try to build an abstract method out of it, you can face a difficulty to check if '`textFrom`' is before '`textTo`'. Otherwise method can return a match for some other occurance of '`textFrom`' in text.

Here is a ready-to-go abstract method that covers this disadvantage:

```
  /**
   * Get text between two strings. Passed limiting strings are not 
   * included into result.
   *
   * @param text     Text to search in.
   * @param textFrom Text to start cutting from (exclusive).
   * @param textTo   Text to stop cuutting at (exclusive).
   */
  public static String getBetweenStrings(
    String text,
    String textFrom,
    String textTo) {

    String result = "";

    // Cut the beginning of the text to not occasionally meet a      
    // 'textTo' value in it:
    result =
      text.substring(
        text.indexOf(textFrom) + textFrom.length(),
        text.length());

    // Cut the excessive ending of the text:
    result =
      result.substring(
        0,
        result.indexOf(textTo));

    return result;
  }
```

Comment: This will not return multiple occurrences when there are multiple matches.  Only the first one.

Comment: Though it returns only first match, fulfills my need.

Answer (score 5):

Your regex looks correct, but you're `splitting` with it instead of `matching` with it. You want something like this:

```
// Untested code
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("<%=(.*?)%>").matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```