# How to extract content between two words in a text file using Java?

Tags: java, r

I have a text file and I want to extract the content between these two words using Java .

I am new to Java ,can anyone help me out ?

This is the method in R language to extract content between words Directions & Ingredients .

```
   sub("."*Directions*(.*?)* Photograph.*,\\1",x)
```

where `x` is the text content .
Can anyone tell me the corresponding code in `Java` .

Thanks

Comment: May be this link helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597303/extract-string-between-two-strings-in-java

Comment: I wouldn't really tag this with R since it's purely a Java question. Look up "regular expressions in java". You should be able to easily translate the regex you have in R to one in Java if you just look up the syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Java [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class:

```
String x = new String("string that contains Directions and Photograph. ");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Directions(.*?) Photograph");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(x); 
while (matcher.find()) {
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Live [DEMO](http://ideone.com/sxLINC)

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to use apache-commons ; this can be elegantly done as :

```
String[] results =  StringUtils.substringsBetween(str,"Directions","Photograph");
```

Where `str` being the string in question.
Dependency you need is `commons-lang-XXX.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Thes simplest way is:

```
    String originalString = "bla, bla, bla, Directions bla ... bla ... bla.... Ingredients ....";
    String result = originalString.substring(originalString.indexOf("Directions")+"Directions".length(), originalString.indexOf("Ingredients"));
    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Using patterns is better as it states the intent clearly. Also, `substring()` when used with large strings (for example, processing a batch file with millions of lines) can lead to unexpected heap issues(a bug fixed in Java1.7)