# How can I get the text between two lines of a text file using java

Tags: java, regex

How can I get the text between two lines of a text file using Java?
I try to do like this but it's not working:

```
String input = "!!!Error deploying file order\\POST_ORDER_UpdateTaxAmountCurrInCo.sql at 22-JUL-16 08:07:Chathura aBhanakana1!!!Error deploying file order\\POST_ORDER_";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\b!!!Error deploying file\\b).*?(?=\\b!!!Error deploying file\\b)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("A " + m.group());
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here ?

Comment: to get the text between the "!!!Error deploying file" text fields.

Comment: I'm not completely sure about your question but I think this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661733/how-to-extract-content-between-two-words-in-a-text-file-using-java

Comment: @ paolo Forgia: These things doesn't work for this.is it changed when having ' //,\\ !,!! kind of symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer

**Using regex**

```
String pattern = "([\\s\\S]*?)(!!!Error deploying file)";
```

Explanation of above pattern.

1. *? -  match a single character between zero and unlimited times
2. \s -  match any white space character
3. \S -  match any non-whitespace character

Example code :

```
String line = "!!!Error deploying file order\\POST_ORDER_UpdateTaxAmountCurrInCo.sql at 22-JUL-16 08:07:Chathura aBhanakana1!!!Error deploying file order\\POST_ORDER_UpdateTaxAmountChathura aBhanakana1AAAAA !!!Error deploying file order\\POST";

String pattern = "([\\s\\S]*?)(!!!Error deploying file)";

// Create a Pattern object
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

// Now create matcher object.
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
while (m.find( )) {
  String str = m.group(1);
  if(str != null && !str.isEmpty()){
     System.out.println("Found value: " + str );
   }
}
```

Output

1. Found value:  order\POST_ORDER_UpdateTaxAmountCurrInCo.sql at
   22-JUL-16 08:07:Chathura aBhanakana1
2. Found value: 
   order\POST_ORDER_UpdateTaxAmountChathura aBhanakana1AAAAA

[Check output here](http://ideone.com/oWvru3)

**Using split method**

Example code :

```
String line = "!!!Error deploying file order\\POST_ORDER_UpdateTaxAmountCurrInCo.sql at 22-JUL-16 08:07:Chathura aBhanakana1!!!Error deploying file order\\POST_ORDER_UpdateTaxAmountChathura aBhanakana1AAAAA !!!Error deploying file order\\POST";

for (String retval: line.split("!!!Error deploying file")){
       System.out.println(retval);
 }
```

Output :

```
1 ) order\POST_ORDER_UpdateTaxAmountCurrInCo.sql at 22-JUL-16 08:07:Chathura aBhanakana1
2) order\POST_ORDER_UpdateTaxAmountChathura aBhanakana1AAAAA
3) order\POST
```

[Check output here](http://ideone.com/0jQNul)

Comment: It's work.But the thing is,if the line has more than two "!!!Error deploying file" this words.it takes the first and last ones.Ex  :!!!Error deploying file Chathura aBhanakana1!!!Error deploying fileAAA!!!Error deploying file ,,:,In here i can't take both words inside the pattern

Comment: @chathuraBhanaka Sorry I didn't understand what you are telling, please provide a example and say what output you want.
For example - 
**My string is this `""`, the output should be this `""`.**
If you have more than one string then provide all different strings with what output you are expecting.

Comment: !!!Error deploying file order\POST_ORDER_UpdateTaxAmountCurrInCo.sql at 22-JUL-16 08:07:Chathura aBhanakana1!!!Error deploying file order\POST_ORDER_UpdateTaxAmountChathura aBhanakana1AAAAA
!!!Error deploying file order\POST;........If you take this as a line in your code.what i want is ::order\POST_ORDER_UpdateTaxAmountCurrInCo.sql at 22-JUL-16 08:07:Chathura aBhanakana1 and                                                                         order\POST_ORDER_UpdateTaxAmountChathura aBhanakana1AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA                      this.because these are in between Pattern

Comment: @chathuraBhanaka I have updated the answer, you can split the string with **!!!Error deploying file** which will give back a String array with data before and after the regex.

Comment: use [non-greedy match](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11898998/995714) `"!!!Error deploying file(.*?)!!!Error deploying file"` (notice the ?) to get the first `!!!Error deploying file` end.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I tried that, its not working. So he wants like this
Example:
String "My cat best cat excellent cat".
Output should be : best, excellent.

Comment: @ Ravikumar,Thank you.It's Work properly

Comment: @chathuraBhanaka If my answer solved your problem then please select it as answer.

Comment: @chathuraBhanaka I have updated my answer, have a look at it.