# Extract specific text in between 2 strings

Tags: javascript, regex

Assume we have text such as the following.

```
Title: (some text)
My Title [abc]

Content: (some test)
My long content paragraph. With multiple sentences. [abc]

Short Content: (some text)
Short content [abc]
```

Using Javascript and RegEx, is it possible to extract the text so that it would be as follows.

```
Title: My Title
Content: My long content paragraph. With multiple sentences.
Short Content: Short content
```

Basically ignoring new lines and text in the `()` and `[]` brackets?

I've tried to use Regex but I can't get it to do exactly as I'd like. I'm also getting the issue that when I match `Content:` i'm getting a match for both `Content:` & `Short Content:` however i'd want to only match the occurrence where it is an exact match.

EDIT:

I'm new to RegEx. So far to extract the *titles* such as Title:, Content: and so on I have

```
/[A-Za-z]+:|[A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+:|[A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+:|[A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+ [0-9]+:/g
```

And then I loop through and use this

```
[TITLENAME]:.*\n.*
```

I'm struggling to get past this. My next step would be to loop through the text that is matched above and then remove the bracket stuff. I'm sure there is a better way to do this!

Comment: Could you attach the RegEx that you tried using?

Comment: Added to the description

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597303/extract-string-between-two-strings-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String.replace( /(\(|\)|\[|\])/g , '')`

If you take a string and use the replace method with these two arguments it will return a string with the `()[]` characters removed. I have escaped them all with `\` since they are special characters in regex. It might be a little over zealous.

Also `g` makes the regular expression global so it will remove all instances

Comment: Actually I misunderstood your question. It should be possible to use string.replace and another regex expression to achieve the result you want though

Comment: `.replace( /(\([^)]*\)|\[[^\]]\])/g, ' ')` So this removes everything in () or [] as well as the brackets and replaces them with a space

Comment: And finally `.replace( /(\([^)]*\)|\[[^\]]*\])\n?/g, ' ')` will hopefully actually work on square brackets unlike my previous version and will remove the new line character after the bracketed text

Comment: If this is the right idea let me know if any issues show up. I will have a go at correcting them later

Comment: Thanks, looking into it now!

Answer (score 0):

If the text within parenthesis (e.g. 'abc') is fixed and have a special meaning you can also go with: `'/(\(some text\)\n|\(some test\)\n|(\[abc\]))|(^$\n)/gm'`.
This way you would allow parenthesis in the real text that you want to preserve, e.g. `some text (this I want to preserve) and other text`.

Please note the multiline `m` flag.

https://regex101.com/r/cS3pRR/1