# JAVA - Getting substring after keyword(in each token), compare it and remove duplicates

Tags: java, regex

I'm writing a duplicate remover for BibTex. The books are listed in that form:

```
@Book{abramowitz+stegun,
    author =    "Milton Abramowitz and Irene A. Stegun",
    title =     "Handbook of Mathematical Functions with
                 Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables",
    publisher = "Dover",
    year =      1964,
    address =   "New York",
    edition =   "ninth Dover printing, tenth GPO printing"
}^
```

What I have done is to read the data from external txt file, and Tokenize them after each book.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package gotowy;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

/**
 *
 * @author Adam
 */
public class DuplicateFinder {
    void deleteDuplicates(File filename) throws IOException{       
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

     String textLine = reader.readLine();
     String dodaj = "";
  do {
    //System.out.println(textLine);

    textLine = reader.readLine();
    dodaj = dodaj + textLine;
  } while(textLine != null);

  reader.close();
        String books;
        books = dodaj;
        System.out.println(books);
        String delimiter = "^";
     StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(books,delimiter);
     int liczbaTokenow = st.countTokens();
     System.out.println(liczbaTokenow);
     System.out.println(st);


    books.substring(books.indexOf("title") + 3 , books.length());


    // while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
       //  System.out.println(st.nextToken()+"xDDDDDDDDDDDD");
     //}

}
}
```

And now I need help with get the substring of the title after every "title" keyword (in each token!!) in my list and compare them. Any ideas?
Thx in advance! :)

Comment: Java is not an acronym.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the title will always be within the quotation marks. The problem will then be the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595019/how-to-get-a-string-between-two-characters), except that the parenthesis should be replaced by quotation marks. So it will be something like:

```
public String getTitle(String s){
  s = s.substring(s.indexOf("\"") + 1);
  s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("\""));
  return s;}
```

Your while-loop would then be:

```
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
String item = st.nextToken();
String substringWithTitle = item.substring(item.indexOf("title"));
String title = getTitle(substringWithTitle);}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(textLine.startwith("title"){
    s = s.substring(textLine.indexOf("\"") + 1);
    s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("\""));f
    System.out.println(s);
}
```