# How to Select the last part from ArrayAdapter.getItem(which)?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-layout

I am selecting an item from arraylist

ArrayAdapter.getItem(which)

I am getting the result as Amazon.com%2C%20Inc.-AMZN

I just want the last part that is AMZN of this string to append in my url.

Answer (score 1):

Normal String operation like [lastIndexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String)) and [substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int))

```
      String str = "Amazon.com%2C%20Inc.-AMZN";

      String result = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);
      System.out.println(result);
```

or if there are no other `-` in the String use

```
 String endBit = str.split ("-")[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this url

[How to get a string between two characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595019/how-to-get-a-string-between-two-characters)

```
String s = "Amazon.com%2C%20Inc.-AMZN";

String result = s.substring(s.indexOf("-") + 1);

System.out.println(result);
```

**Output:** AMZN

Comment: OP wants the end bit

Answer (score 0):

try this.

if there is no other -

```
String val = "Amazon.com%2C%20Inc.-AMZN";
String arr[]=val.split("-");
and at index 1 you can get your value.
like arr[1]// this will contain "AMZN"
```