# Splitting a string at a defined sign - especially "("

Tags: java, android, split

I have a little problem with splitting a String

```
String anl_gewerk = "Text Text Text (KG 412/2)"
String[] parts = anl_gewerk.split("[(]");
anl_gewerk = parts[1];
anl_gewerk = anl_gewerk.replaceAll("\\(","").replaceAll("\\)","");
anl_gewerk = anl_gewerk.replace("KG","");
```

I have the aforementioned string, and I'm searching for "412/2".
Therefore, I want to split the String into two substrings searching for "(".
Finally I want to grab this String deleting "(", "KG", " " and ")".

When I select `anl_gewerk = parts[0];` it works but I get the wrong part, when I change into parts[1] the App crashes.

Please help me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12595052/1848157 , refer this .

Comment: Next step is , you need to split that newly string using #space , " " .

Comment: try this: String anl_gewerk = "Text Text Text (KG 412/2)"
String[] parts = anl_gewerk.split("(");
String anl_gewerk1 = parts[1];
String[] parts2= anl_gewerk1.split(" ");
String anl_gewerk2 = parts2[1];
String[] parts3=anl_gewerk2.split(")");
String finalString=parts3[0];

Comment: Voted to close as not reproducible: http://ideone.com/6vyy6m

Comment: This is working fine `String anl_gewerk = "Text Text Text (KG 412/2)";
 String[] parts = anl_gewerk.split("[(]");
 anl_gewerk = parts[1];
 anl_gewerk = anl_gewerk.replaceAll("\\(","").replaceAll("\\)","");
 anl_gewerk = anl_gewerk.replace("KG","").trim();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a string between two characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595019/how-to-get-a-string-between-two-characters)

Comment: Thanks for all the answer. I have tried every answer, but it dosen´t work...

Comment: Is it maybe because of the "/"?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code by this:

```
    String anl_gewerk = "Text Text Text (KG 412/2)";
    String[] parts = anl_gewerk.split("[(]");
    anl_gewerk = parts[1];
    String sub[] = anl_gewerk.split(" ");
    String test = sub[1];
    String result = test.replace(")","");// it gives your result 412/2
```