# How to update excel values from rest assured json response using apache-poi

Tags: rest, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am new to Rest Assured. I have stored below Request in excel and successfully i am retrieving and sending also.. but while sending, i need to add 'Transaction tag'  from another api response which i already stored in Object(TTAG).

So how to pass `TTATG` obj in 'transaction tag' during run time. Please suggest an idea.

```
Request:
{
  "transaction_tag": "Enter transaction tag",
  "transaction_type": "capture",
}
```

Comment: Hi, Please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), We need to see the complete code

Comment: @WilfredClement Thank you for looking in to my question..

I found solution from this below page.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595019/how-to-get-a-string-between-two-characters

Comment: I found solution from this below page. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595019/how-to-get-a-string-between-two-characters