# How to get an exact string between two characters in java

Tags: java, substring, special-characters

I have a string variable in Java with the value below:

```
String str = "web > data > list > new_list.html";
```

I want my final string like so:

```
String str = "new_list.html";
```

I have tried like this:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\>.]");
final String[] result = pattern.split(str);
```

But it is returning `data > list > new_list.html`

How can i get exact substring `new_list.html`?

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595019/how-to-get-a-string-between-two-characters/18096365#18096365

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a string between two characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595019/how-to-get-a-string-between-two-characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
String s =  "web > data > list > new_list.html";

String newList = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("> ") + 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String str = "web > data > list > new_list.html";
str = str.substring(20);
```