# How to extract a substring from a sentence until a delimeter

Tags: java, regex

Hi I have some string like this:

```
location/city/home-a-berlin?/someNewAdress
```

I want to extract word berlin which placed between "-a-" and "?". How can i do that with regex in java?

I can do it by using string API but kinda stuck with regex.

```
String cityName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("-a-")+3, url.indexOf('?')) //berlin
```

Comment: See [How to get a string between two characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54088811/3832970)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a capture group with a negated character class.

```
-a-([^\?]+)\?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3lpGpR/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/HCErw5)

In Java:

```
String regex = "-a-([^\\?]+)\\?";
String string = "location/city/home-a-berlin?/someNewAdress\n";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output

```
berlin
```

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
s = s.replaceAll(".*-(.*?)\\?.*", "$1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative regex:

```
 "-a-(.+?)\\?"
```

Regex in testbench and context:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input1 = "location/city/home-a-berlin?/someNewAdress";
    List<String> inputs = Arrays.asList(input1);

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-a-(.+?)\\?");
    List<String> results = inputs.stream().map(s -> pattern.matcher(s))
            .filter(Matcher::find).map(m -> m.group(1)).collect(Collectors.toList());

    //Output:
    results.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Output:

```
berlin
```

Summary of regular-expression constructs:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html