# Escaping individual characters in a character class

Tags: java, android, regex, escaping

How can I escape individual regex metacharacters in Java?

For an Android app, I am working with files that contain many characters that regexes consider to have a special meaning. These include `\?.()[*\^+'` and `-`. I will be reading in two files:

1. A dictionary list of words, each on a separate line.
2. A list of characters that can be used to filter the words in the dictionary list.

A sample of each follows.

*Dictionary:*

```
 /it*
 t1*]
 ?\<t
 item
```

(Yes, these are words. The first three are the contracted [Braille ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille_ASCII) representations of the words "stitch", "teacher", and "thought". Now you know.)

*"Letters" to use:*

```
?]*/\<1eitm
```

I want to include these letters in a regular expression similar to this:

```
String letters = "?]*/\<1eitm";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^["+letters+"]{4}$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

My aim is to select all the words from the dictionary list that include only the given characters *and* are the given length. I cannot control the order in which the requested characters will appear in the file.

If I use only non-metacharacters, like `<1eitm`, this works fine. Somehow, I need to escape the metacharacters and ensure that characters such as `]` and `-` appear in the right place inside the square brackets.

I could do this manually...but am hoping that there is a built-in command to do this for me. All I have found so far is the `Pattern.quote()` command, which does not give me the results I want.

Below is a list of all the characters that I may need to use inside the square brackets:

```
\_-,;:!?.'"()[]@*/\&#%^+<=>~$0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

And here is the barebones code that I am using for my Android test:

```
package com.example.quote;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AssetManager am = this.getAssets();
        try {
            String dictionary = readFile(am, "dictionary.txt");
            String regex = readFile(am, "regex.txt");

            regex = "^["+regex+"]{4}$"; // THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO MAKE A CHANGE

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(dictionary);

            while (matcher.find()) {
                Log.d("TEST", matcher.group(0));
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String readFile(AssetManager am, String fileName) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = am.open(fileName);

        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();

        String string = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");

        return string;
    }
}
```

Comment: Related and possibly helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10664434/1810429

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Pattern.quote()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) to quote all the special characters and make them matches literal character. The function is usually implemented by surrounding the String supplied with quoting `\Q...\E` construct.

In Oracle/OpenJDK (reference) implementation, which surrounds the String with `\Q...\E` construct, the quoted construct is recognized inside character class from Java 6, so the returned value can be used inside character class.

Android uses [ICU implementation](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp), which according to the documentation, also allows `\Q` and `\E` to work inside character class. Therefore, regardless of how the `Pattern.quote()` function works in ICU (adding escape `\` or using quoting `\Q...\E` construct), it should work similar to the reference implementation (Java 6) in this regard.

```
regex = "^[" + Pattern.quote(regex) + "]{4}$";
```

Comment: After some experimentation, I find that `regex = "^["+Pattern.quote(regex)+"]{4}$";` does the job for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Escaping special characters for Java regular expressions is annoying, but not difficult. The reason is that the backslash character `\` is an escape character in Java strings, so the literal string "\" is a backslash. But a single backslash is also an escape character in regular expressions, so in a Java regex pattern-matching string, special characters should be "escaped" with a double backslash! Hence, in order to match a question mark character `?` your regex would have to include `\\?`. And to match a single backslash, your regex would have to include `\\\\`.

Let's take your `String` as an example:

```
String letters = "?]*/\<1eitm";
```

The first five characters here should be escaped - that is, prefixed with a double backslash escape sequence `\\`:

```
String letters = "\\?\\]\\*\\/\\\\<1eitm";
```

And the backslash, itself, as pointed out above, has to be prefixed with the escape sequence and then doubled itself.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I understand, from what you are not saying, that there is no built-in command that will perform all this escaping automatically. Is that right? In other words, I will have to manually check the input string and add `\\` or `\\\` before any metacharacter that I find.

Comment: When I test [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html), I see that the Java String expression that works is this: `"(?m)^[]?*/\\\\<1eitm]{4}$"`. In other words, only the `\` character needs to be triple-escaped, and the `]` character needs to be placed at the beginning.

Comment: Yes, my apologies, that is because they are inside the square brackets `[]` bookending the character class. I missed that.