# How to escape special characters in a regex pattern in java?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string :

```
Patient:
${ss.patient.howard.firstName} ${ss.patient.howard.lastName}
Gender: ${ss.patient.howard.sex}
Birthdate: ${ss.patient.howard.dob}
${ss.patient.howard.addressLine1}
Phone: (801)546-4765
```

and I am trying to replace `${..}` substrings with other strings so it would look like:

```
Patient:
firstName lastName

Gender:sex
Birthdate: dob
addressLine1
Phone: (801)546-4765
```

Comment: I am trying examleString.replaceFirst("\\${(.*?)\\}", (String) TestcaseContext.getCache().get(matcher.group(1))) and getting, Illegal repetition near index 1
\${(.*?)\}

Comment: may be [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664434/escaping-special-characters-in-java-regular-expressions) will guide you in right direction?

Comment: Must you use regular expressions? I would consider the [Apache Commons Lang StrSubstitutor](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrSubstitutor.html) for this particular application. It does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex with a capturing group:

```
String myString = "Patient:\n${ss.patient.howard.firstName} ${ss.patient.howard.lastName}\nGender: ${ss.patient.howard.sex}\nBirthdate: ${ss.patient.howard.dob}\n${ss.patient.howard.addressLine1}\nPhone: (801)546-4765";
myString = myString.replaceAll("\\$\\{[^}]+?\\.([^.}]+)}", "$1");

System.err.println(myString);
```

`([^.}]+)` is the capturing group before `}` and after the last DOT.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dZ5jY6/1)

**Output:**

```
Patient:
firstName lastName
Gender: sex
Birthdate: dob
addressLine1
Phone: (801)546-4765
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, good to know about the capturing group. It did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could try searching for `${string.string.string` OR `}` and replace with `empty` string or `nothing` like this.

**Regex:** `\${[a-z]+\.[a-z]+\.[a-z]+\.|}`

**Replacement to do:** Replace with nothing or empty string.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mW2iJ3/1)**