# How to pass escaped [aabb] to replaceAll() method in java?

Tags: java

I want to replace a string "[aabb]" in a txt file, but if I wanted to use replaceAll("[aabb]", "x"); method for this replacement, java sees that as a regular expression. How can I escape "[aabb]" string?

Comment: Use Pattern.quote in general case, or "\\\[aabb\\\]" for your particular case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escaping special characters in Java Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664434/escaping-special-characters-in-java-regular-expressions)

Comment: use `str.replace()` instead of `str.replaceAll()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try one of these -

```
Pattern.quote("[aabb]")
```

OR make the string `"\\Q[aabb]\\E"` [remember `\` needs to be quoted for Java strings].

As well as lots of great answers on SO - go to the [javadoc for Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape `[` and `]` as they are the meta-characters used to specify [character classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) i.e. if you do not escape them, the regex engine will treat `[aabb]` as one of the characters within the square bracket.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Hello [aabb] World";
        str = str.replaceAll("\\[aabb\\]", "x");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello x World
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replaceAll(Pattern.quote("[aabb]"),"x")`