# regex to replace string is not working correctly

Tags: java

I have a string and I need to replace `|| '-' ||` with `,` using regex.
Please find the code below:

```
String str= "str1 || '-' || str2";
str.replaceAll("|| '-' || ", ",");
```

This replaceAll method is not working. Can anyone please suggest the correct way.

Output should be: `str1,str2`

Comment: In java, `String`s are immutable. You are not actually reassigning your `str` variable with the result of the `replaceAll`. Also, `replaceAll` takes a regular expression as an input. Use [`replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) if you don't actually want to work with regex (this way you wont have to deal with things such as escaping the pipes).

Comment: Every `|` must escaped with backslash. So try `\|\|`.

Comment: You should use replace (which doesn't take a regex) rather than replaceAdd (which does).

Comment: @JonnyHenly The pipe is in regex the or operator. According regex101.com confirms my words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following statement:

```
String strMod = str.replaceAll("\\s\\|\\| '-' \\|\\| ", ",");
```

The strMod variable will contain the modified value.

The key points are:

- use escape char in the regular expression because the pipe character has a special meaning in the regexp
- use the result value of the replaceAll method

Comment: Not sure why this is the accepted answer. There is no actual use case for using regex here. Only some simple text replacement. So why go the way of escaping the whole thing, instead of simply suggesting to use `replace` instead of `replaceAll`?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `replaceAll()`, rather use `replace()` because replaceAll uses regex and you do not need regex in this situation.

```
str = str.replace("|| '-' || ", ",");
```

If you are here because you have to use regex, the pipe character (`|`) is a special regex character and in this situation you would need to escape special characters by using a `\` character infront.

As shown here:
[Escaping special characters in Java Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664434/escaping-special-characters-in-java-regular-expressions)

Comment: The best solution, not using regex. But you could mention that `|` is a special regex symbol.

Answer (score 1):

The `|` character has special meaning in regex. You can escape it by prefixing it with a `\`. You can also use `Pattern.quote()` to escape the whole string.

But in this case it might be better not to use a regex. You want to replace literal text. Try `str.replace("|| '-' || ", ",")`.

Comment: According https://regex101.com , only the pipe must be escaped.