# How to represent the double quotes character (") in regex?

Tags: java, regex, char

I need to use regex, to check if a string starts with a *double quotes* character (`"`) and ends with a *double quotes* character too.

The problem is I can't use a *double quotes* character, cause it gets confused. Is there any other way to represent a *double quotes* character `"` in regex, or in string in general?

```
String s = """;    // ?
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enter quotes in a String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559063/how-to-enter-quotes-in-a-string) or [Java, escaping (using) quotes in a regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398365/java-escaping-using-quotes-in-a-regex) or ...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Firstly, double quote character is nothing special in regex - it's just another character, so it doesn't need escaping *from the perspective of regex*.

However, because Java uses double quotes to *delimit* String constants, if you want to create a string in Java with a double quote in it, you must escape them.

This code will test if your String matches:

```
if (str.matches("\".*\"")) {
    // this string starts and end with a double quote
}
```

Note that you don't need to add *start* and *end* of input markers (`^` and `$`) in the regex, because `matches()` requires that the whole input be matched to return true - `^` and `$` are implied.

Comment: A fun one to match content inside quotes which I often use for properties in xml tags is `"[^"]*"` (or, as escaped java string, `"\"[^\"]*\""`). Impossible to bleed out ;)

Answer (score 10):

you need to use backslash before ". like `\"`

From the doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) you can see that

> A character preceded by a backslash ( \ ) is an escape sequence and has
>   special meaning to the compiler.

and " (double quote) is a escacpe sequence

When an escape sequence is encountered in a print statement, the compiler interprets it accordingly. For example, if you want to put quotes within quotes you must use the escape sequence, \", on the interior quotes. To print the sentence

> She said "Hello!" to me.

you would write

> System.out.println("She said \"Hello!\" to me.");