# How to represent the double quotes character (") in regex using CakePHP?

Tags: php, regex, string, cakephp

I am very new to CakePHP and not very familiar with regular expressions.

I need to use regex in CakePHP to check whether a string has a double quotes character, followed immediately by a comma, then followed by another double quotes character: ","

Here is my attempt: 
String::tokenize($problem_string, **'/",/"'**);

I tried ($problem_string, **","**), but that parsed the string at every place there was a comma. I also tried ($problem_string, **"/",/""**), with no luck.

This entry suggests using a backslash in front of the double quotes in Java, but maybe that rule doesn't apply for PHP or CakePHP?
[How to represent the double quotes character (") in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761596/how-to-represent-the-double-quotes-character-in-regex)

I feel like this should be an easy problem to figure out, but I've been stumped for quite a while now.

Comment: That's a forward slash, not a backslash \.

Comment: Escape with a backslash rather than a forward slash, in other words `\"`

Comment: `String::tokenize()` doesn't use regular expressions, but `strpos()`.

Answer (score 1):

The escape character you're looking for is the backslash not the forward slash, **but** you don't have to escape double quotes if you use single quote delimiters, so just this: `($problem_string, '/","/')`

#### Update

After reading `String::tokenize` docs, and not seeing any mention of regex, I think you just want `($problem_string, '","')`

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried ($problem_string, '/","/') but had no luck. I also tried ($problem_string, '\","\'), ($problem_string, '\",\"'), and ($problem_string, '","'). I did notice that substr_count($problem_string, '","') works fine, which seems strange.

Comment: I'm looking up `String::tokenize` and nothing in there suggests that the second argument is a regex, what makes you think this has anything to do with regex?

Comment: Did you notice that I updated my answer with a non-regex solution?  Does that work?  (also, don't forget to upvote the people here who took the time to steer you in the right direction - it's the StackOverflow way)